# very simple Signal Processing

Tags: python, numpy

I am processing a very simple signal like this:

```
import numpy as np

series = np.random.random(20)
blind = np.zeros(series.size)

for ii in np.arange(blind.size-1):
    if series[ii+1]-series[ii]>0.4:
        blind[ii] = 1
```

However, this does not look Numpythonic at all! How can I rewrite the code to use the Numpy-way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
blind[series[1:] - series[:-1] > 0.4] = 1
```

or following suggestion from `tk`

```
blind[np.diff(series) > 0.4] = 1
```

The key point being that you use [boolean/logical indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) (i.e. indexing with a boolean array) instead of a loop and an if statement.

Comment: Thank you for the examples! I was looking for a neat solution like this! It looks so much prettier ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You mean something like ? 
np.diff(series)>0.4